# Flutter: Horizontal listview break to next line and expandable

Tags: flutter, dart, user-interface, mobile

[UI mockup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WgnDP.png)

I have this above UI to develop using Flutter. I have already put the `ListView.builder` widget to build a horizontal list.

[Code so far](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IxxiP.png)

```
            Container(
          height: 60,
          padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 10, right: 10,top:0),
          child: ListView.builder(
            physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
            shrinkWrap: true,
            scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
            itemCount:storeProvider.categories.length,
            itemBuilder:(BuildContext context, int index) => GestureDetector(
              child: GestureDetector(
                onTap: (){
                  FocusScope.of(context).requestFocus(new FocusNode());
                  if(storeProvider.cloudCategoryId ==  storeProvider.categories[index].id){
                    storeProvider.setCategoryId("");
                    storeProvider.resetCategory();
                  }else {
                    storeProvider.setCategoryId(
                        storeProvider.categories[index].id
                    );
                    storeProvider.resetCategory();
                    storeProvider.categories[index].productCategory.isSelected =
                    true;
                    storeProvider.searchStoreProducts(
                        context, storeProvider.keyword);
                  }
                },
                child:
                storeProvider.categories[index].productCategory.category != null
                    ?SearchCategoryItem(
                  title: storeProvider.categories[index].productCategory.category,
                  isSelected: storeProvider.categories[index].productCategory.isSelected,
                ):Container(),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
```

But I couldn't find a way to break the pills to next line and limit to 3 lines. When we press the See more text it needs to expand and show all the pills.

Answer (score 1):

I think the cleaner approach to this is to use `Wrap()` widget instead of `ListView.builder`:

Here's a example:

```
Wrap(
    for (int x = 0; x < categories.length; x++)...[
         OutlinedButton(
             onPressed: () {},
             child: Text("Category $x"),
         )
    ]
)
```

Answer (score 0):

In my suggestion, As per your design that you have mocked up you must try grid view with random width size ,
try https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_staggered_grid_view

```
MasonryGridView.count(
crossAxisCount: 4,
mainAxisSpacing: 4,
crossAxisSpacing: 4,
itemBuilder: (context, index) {
 return Tile(
  index: index,
  extent: (index % 5 + 1) * 100,
);
```

},
);